# Problems aggregating data from Kafka in Flink

Tags: java, stream, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I created a simple Flink application which reads logs from a Kafka topic, aggregate them in a window whose duration is 2 seconds with a watermark of 1 second. Then I send the results to another Kafka Topic. The application is deployed on a cluster.

I consume kafka like this:

```
Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    parameters.put("bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers);
    parameters.put("group.id", groupId);
    parameters.put("zookeeper.connect", zookeeperConnect);
    parameters.put("topic", inputTopic);
    parameters.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");

ParameterTool parameterTool = ParameterTool.fromMap(parameters);

return env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer011<>(parameterTool.getRequired("topic"),
    new SimpleStringSchema(),
    parameterTool.getProperties()));
```

Aggregation is made with:

```
DataStream<AggregatedMeasures> aggregatedStream = messageStream

    // Extract the timestamp from the object
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new TimestampExtractor())

    //Key for the Aggregation
    .keyBy(new KeySelector<MeasureData, Tuple2<String, Timestamp>>() {
      @Override
      public Tuple2<String, Timestamp> getKey(MeasureData value) throws Exception {
        return Tuple2.of(value.Id(), value.getEventTimestamp());
      }
    })

    //Set the Time Window Duration
    .timeWindow(Time.seconds(windowDuration))

    //Aggregate
    .aggregate(new AggregateMeasureFunction());
```

I produce to Kafka like this:

```
producer = new FlinkKafkaProducer011<>(
    bootstrapServers, // broker list
    outputTopic, // target topic
    new AggregatedMeasuresJSONSerializer()); // serialization schema

producer.setWriteTimestampToKafka(true);

messageStream.addSink(producer); // DataStream<AggregatedMeasures>
```

I tested it while producing in the input topic one million logs. This producer written in Python is slow and Flink works well in live.

When I try then to read the same input topic which is already filled with one million logs, the Flink producer reads the logs but doesn't output all the results, only part of them.

Is it backpressure? I don't understand that behaviour.

I'm using Java 8, Flink 1.4 and YARN.

Comment: Can you tell us a little bit more about which results are produced? Are these results from a specific time range?

Comment: The produced results are good, it's just that I don't have all of them. For example, when I produced one million message in Kafka in 20 minutes, the program returns 400217 aggregated messages, which is the good result. However when Flink is directly plugged into the topic which is already filled with one million message, the program returns me only 300123 messages. When I check the produced messages, it seems that the last events produced by my program are not the last one I should receive. Maybe the last messages are lost? What do you mean by a "specific time range" @TillRohrmann ?

Comment: Could it be that you still have some open windows whose results have not been triggered? You should make sure that you have a constantly increasing watermark. So, for example, if you have consumed all your Kafka input data and nothing is added to the topic anymore, then the watermark will stay the same and Flink won't trigger the in progress windows.

Comment: I've just tried to push more data while the current flink job was running in order to update the watermark. It looks like the only way to do it. Unfortunately, I still have the issue...